# Room Insert ContentValues by using SqLiteOpenHelper methods

Tags: android, android-room, sqliteopenhelper, content-values

I am using `Room` to manage SQLite databasae in my app. The thing is that I am migrating a project, in which I download some data from a private webservice and finally I am receiving a `ContentValues` object which contains all the data to save to my POJO (let's say UserPojo). Because I have this ContentValues object, I initially thought in using the `SqLiteOpenHelper's insert` method, but I do not know how to get an instance of it from my `RoomDatabase`, neither whether it is a good practice to implement, neither how to alternatively do it...

What I tried was the following:

```
MyDatabase.getDatabaseInstance(MyApplication.getAppContext()).getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().insert(currentTable, CONFLICT_NONE, rowValues);
```

Is it okey? Where should I call it from? `ViewModel`? A new `DAO`? How shall I do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting into Room, then you would have an Entity which is really a normal class with annotations so that Room can create and access the table.

As such you could create an instance(s) of the class/entity from the ContentValues (using the appropriate get methods) and then use Room to insert(s) (@Insert).

- see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues#get(java.lang.String)

Comment: the thing was to use a generic method, avoiding switching the entity, in other words, a method working for all tables just passing the tableName as parameter